# Do 같이 and 함께 mean the same thing?

Tags: meaning, adverbs, difference

Do 같이 and 함께 mean the same thing? If they are different then how do I know which one to use?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For the meaning "together", they are interchangable, but I'd say 같이 is more colloquial.

같이 has other meanings though. These are not interchangable with 함께.

1. like(adverb) : 선생님이 하는 것과 같이 하세요. (Do it like the teacher does it)
2. like(particle) : 얼음장같이 차가운 방바닥 (room floor as cold as ice)
3. emphasizing a time : 새벽같이 떠나다 (leave in the early morning)